# Cannot convert reponse.data to string in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TaskOneServices from '../services/TaskOneServices'
import circle from '../assets/icons/dry-clean.png'
import tick from '../assets/icons/check-mark.png'

async function showImage (taskId)  {

    var getStatus = (await TaskOneServices.getStatus(taskId))?.data;

    JSON.stringify(getStatus);

    console.log(typeof(getStatus)); //prints object

    console.log(getStatus === "CREATED"); //prints false

    if(getStatus === "CREATED") {
        return (
            <img className="img-lm" src={circle} alt="bullets" onClick={(ev) => {taskCompleted(ev, taskId)}}/>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <img className="img-lm" src={tick} alt="checked" onClick={(ev) => {taskCompleted(ev, taskId)}}/>
        )
    } 
    
}

function taskCompleted(e, taskid) {
    if(e.target.getAttribute('src') === circle) {
        e.target.setAttribute( 'src', tick);
        e.target.setAttribute( 'alt', 'checked');
        updateTask(taskid);
        // strikeThroughFn(taskid);
    } else {
        e.target.setAttribute( 'src', circle);
        e.target.setAttribute( 'alt', 'bullets');
        updateTask(taskid);
    }
    }

    function updateTask(id) {

        JSON.stringify(id);
        TaskOneServices.updateTask(id).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        });
    }

export default class TaskListComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            task_one:[],
        }

        this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this)
        // this.updateTask = this.updateTask.bind(this)
    }
    //------- showing error -------------
    componentDidMount() {
        TaskOneServices.getTasks().then((response) => {
            this.setState({task_one: response.data})
        });
    }
    //------- showing error -------------

    deleteTask = (id) => {
        
        JSON.stringify(id);
        TaskOneServices.deleteTask(id).then((response) => {
            this.refreshPage();
        });
    }
    
    refreshPage = () => {
        window.location.reload();
    }

    strikeThroughFn(taskid) {
        // JSON.stringify(taskString);
        console.log(taskid);
        var fetchTask = document.getElementById('strikeTask');
        fetchTask.innerHTML = <strike> + {taskid} + </strike>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid bg-white">
                <div className="row">
                    <table className="table border-bottom table-pad">
                        <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.task_one.map(
                                task =>
                                <tr key = {task.id}>
                                    <td width="60px">
                                         {showImage(task.id)}
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="strikeTask">{task.task}</td>
                                    <td width="60px">
                                        <button type="button" className="close text-danger btn-close-style" onClick={() => this.deleteTask(task.id)}>
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to compare the getStatus and string "CREATED" and if both are equal I want to return the inner block of code. But getStatus has a type of object and "CREATED" is a string. So it returns false. I tried JSON.stringify() and it still returns false. Is there any way that I could convert that object to string?

Comment: Be careful with `typeof`, it will tell you an array IS an object.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals Is there any way that I could compare response.data and string?

Comment: It appears that `getStatus` is a promise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: As Brian said right before me, you should async/await your call to `TaskOneServices` and then figure it out from there

Comment: You should be using `useEffect` to update state with the new data, and use the new state to render the component's JSX.

Comment: Also, if this is a React component you should be using PascalCase for the component name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a promise so the .then() will be triggered after your function, you want to await the result of the promise and so use the await keyword with an async function.
REMEMBEr that async function return also a promise

```
async function showImage (taskId)  {

    var getStatus = (await TaskOneServices.getStatus(taskId))?.data;

    JSON.stringify(getStatus);

    console.log(typeof(getStatus)); //prints object

    console.log(getStatus === "CREATED"); //prints false

    if(getStatus === "CREATED") {
        return (
            <img className="img-lm" src={circle} alt="bullets" onClick={(ev) => {taskCompleted(ev, taskId)}}/>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <img className="img-lm" src={tick} alt="checked" onClick={(ev) => {taskCompleted(ev, taskId)}}/>
        )
    } 
    
}
```

Comment: If you're using `async/await` there's little point in using `then` too.

Comment: @Andy true ! I will update this post

Comment: @Andy This worked and now it has the type of string. But another part of the code is showing some errors. I will edit my quesetion.

Comment: @AneeshEdavalathS did you just copy Saren's answer as an edit to your question?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html. You need to understand that you can't use traditional JS (like `querySelector`, for example) with React. React has its own process for updating the DOM.

Comment: @Andy Yeah! Could you please explain to me what that async and await does? I'm a beginner in ReactJS.

Comment: [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) won't fix the problems with your code. Take another look at the "Getting started" link I posted.